# jquery ajax callback function without dynamic parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I have an array with objects, I want to save each one of them via GET, and update certain params in the callback, bot

the html:

```
<html><body><div id='test'><div id="a">a</div><div id="b">b</div></div></body></html>
```

the js:

```
$.map($("#test > div"), save)

save = function(o,i){
 itt = $(o)
 tmp = {'desc':itt.html()};
 $.get('ajax/update_post', {'data':array2json(tmp)}, function(a){ 
   alert(itt.attr('id'))
   updatePostBack(a,itt)
   })
 }

updatePostBack = function(a,item){
 alert(item.attr('id'))
}
```

the updatePostBack is always receiving the las item!
how can I pass the right id or object to a callback function in js / jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is so sadly mundane: you needed to add `var` in front of your variables to declare them as new. They were being overwritten inappropriately by the next iteration before the first one could complete. This code works for me:

```
save = function(o,i){
    var itt = $(o)
    var tmp = {'desc':itt.html()};
    $.get('ajax/update_post', {'data':array2json(tmp)}, function(a){
        alert(itt.attr('id'))
        updatePostBack(a,itt)
    })
}

updatePostBack = function(a,item){
    alert(item.attr('id'))
}

$.map($("#test > div"), save);
```

I also moved the map statement to the end so that it's calling the save function *after* it's been declared.

Comment: ok, I tested this solution and it certainly is. 
thank you a lot, Javascript Lord u.u